# magento xmlrpc session expires immediately

Tags: java, api, magento, session, xml-rpc

First up; this question is similar to another as-yet unresolved question: [call to magento soap api expires immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925645/call-to-magento-soap-api-expires-immediately)

I am working on an XMLRPC-based client-server module. The Magento-based server has several API methods exposed to a Java-based client. I use the standard Java XMLRPC Jars in my client.

I have a "login" call that retrieves a session. I then pass this around to do different calls. I checked that this returns (What looks like) a valid session.

```
Object result1 = client.execute("login", ob1);
session = (String) result1;
```

The next call I make using this session, though, fails with:

```
org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Session expired. Try to relogin.
```

**What I have verified:**

- Set the Session Timeout in Magento to a high value

  - This does not work
- Verify Server time setting is ok

  - it is.
- Verify API user is "Active" in Magento

  - Yep.
- Check the `api_session` table for the session hash

  - See below.

**api_session table**

- This does not have my current session hash.
- It also has only 11 entries; I have logged in about 50 times atleast.
- Session log times vary significantly from `select CURRENT_TIME`

  - Update: This is irrelevant (MySQL is recording in GMT)

Here is what I see:

```
mysql> select * from api_session limit 50;
+---------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
| user_id | logdate             | sessid                           |
+---------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|       5 | 2013-02-01 16:01:49 | 9099b50
|       5 | 2013-02-01 16:02:10 | 7312c1a
|       5 | 2013-02-01 16:05:43 | a6ce30c
+---------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select CURRENT_TIME;
+--------------+
| CURRENT_TIME |
+--------------+
| 14:58:03     |
+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ummm.... This may have been due to my own need for security.

In the above failures my login method took tips from this article: [Irretrievably destroying data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120380/irretrievably-destroying-data-in-java)

Like that article advised, I was passing a char array to the login method. This was ultimately resulting in empty credentials being passed to the `login` method.

The flow to those who may be unfamiliar is

- The login method that gets called is in `Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php`
- This calls the login method in `Mage/Api/Model/Session.php`
- I dumped the inputs into log, they came up empty.

I went back to using my regular, non-secure method of directly passing strings to the method. That worked!

EDIT: Of course this has the disadvantage that I'm back to using strings instead of char[] arrays. Will update answer if I figure out how to do that.

Comment: Of course. I was hoping I'd find out how to pass char[] arrays to XMLRPC calls (and thereby retain the security I had earlier). That will have to be another day though.