# soap api throwing session expired error using nu soap in magento

Tags: magento, session, soap, response

First my site was running with Apache, that time shop api request from other server accepted successfully by magento, but now my server use nginx with magento php version 5.3.10 after that the shop api request from other server not accepting and showing error:

> Session expired Try to relogin. 
>   Array ( [faultcode] => 5 [faultstring] => Session expired. Try to relogin. ) Array5: Session expired. Try to relogin.

I also check web-service user and role which is used by other server to sent request to update my order status in magento.

Is it any misconfiguration or php version problem?